# Retrieve variables of each task in a process activiti

Tags: activiti

I am new to Activiti and have little experience , my question is : 
How to retrieve variables of each task in a process ?

Comment: Are you looking to retrieve the process instance variables or the variables defined on the task itself (taskLocalVariables)?

Comment: i'm looking to retrive taskLocalVariables

Answer (score 3):

For a userTask with id="taskTest" you can use this code:

```
 RuntimeService runtimeService;
 ProcessEngine  activitiProcessEngine
 TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
 runtimeService = activitiProcessEngine.getRuntimeService();
 taskService = activitiProcessEngine.getTaskService();
 Map<String, Object> vars =taskService.createTaskQuery().
 processInstanceId(pi.getId()).taskDefinitionKey("taskTest")
        .singleResult().getProcessVariables();
```

you can use this too : [Variables](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/)

Answer (score 2):

For a userTask with id="task1" you can use taskService [How to get task variables](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/bpm-archive/how-to-get-task-variables/m-p/107347#comment-18754)

```
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskDefinitionKey("task1").includeProcessVariables().orderByTaskCreateTime().desc().list();

for (Task task : tasks) {
    Map<String, Object> variables = task.getProcessVariables();
}
```

Comment: The link provided How to get task variables is not working by now and unreacheable (

Comment: It seems you need to register and login to access the archived forum

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read task local variables into the process instance, you will need to add a taskListener against the "complete" event. If we are talking simple variable mapping, you can use a scriptListener, otherwise a Java class.

Within the listener, you have access to the "execution" (script listener) or the TaskDelegate where you can set/get process instance variables (getVariables() and setVariable()) or local variables getVariableLocal() and setVariableLocal().

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks you , but i need to retrive local variables without execution , i need to collect these informations from Bmpn2.0 xml file

Comment: For service and send tasks, the ioSpecification stanza is used to map task local variables in the BPMN 2.0 XML file. However, I dont believe user tasks enable ioSpecification in Activiti yet.